# File-specific namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm wondering if there's something like a file-specific namespace in C++. Something like the following:

```
namespace thisFile
{
    // whatever code
};
using namespace thisFile;
```

where thisFile might get translated to some unique thing, such as:

```
namespace FAJIW0E0RTI43LNAFWENA
{
    // whatever code
};
using namespace FAJIW0E0RTI43LNAFWENA;
```

or perhaps there is an alternative convenient way to accomplish the same thing (i.e. without manually specifying a unique namespace).

Comment: Take a look at anonymous namespaces, it's pretty much what you're looking for but it's not 'file specific', rather translation unit specific ( iirc ).

Comment: Ylisar: Yes, you "rc".  bean: simply leave off the name for the namespace; the using declaration isn't necessary (unnamed namespaces behave as if it's there).  So you do: namespace { /* code here */ }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
   ... 
}
```